# tcsh alias - find FreeBSD port

Tags: freebsd, alias, tcsh, bsd-ports

I am trying to create an *alias for **tcsh***. I would like to find a program in ports (FreeBSD ports).

So far I made an alias, which works, but finds only ports which end in `*port_name`. I would like it to search for `*port_name*`. Can you tell why my example does not work?

```
alias najdi 'echo /usr/ports/*/*\!:1* | sed -e "y/ /\n/"'
```

.

```
najdi port_name
finds: *port_name
expected: *port_name*
```

**SOLUTION:**
I switched to this: (it is also case in-sensitive)

```
alias portfind 'cd /usr/ports && make quicksearch name=\!:1 | grep Path'
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a function instead?

Comment: I dont know what is function (in this context). After quick search, i found "TIP#1: Overcome lack of functions With a clever use of alias and scripts, lack of 'functions' can be easily overcome." http://www.tcsh.org/TipsAndTricks

Comment: You may want to look at `ports-mgmt/psearch`, does the same with more options.

Answer (score 1):

In tcsh the expansion `!:1*` is equivalent to `!:1-$`

To achieve what you want you need to do this:

```
alias najdi 'echo /usr/ports/*/*\!:1-1* | sed -e "y/ /\n/"'
```

Personally I prefer to use `find` instead of shell expansion:

```
alias najdi 'find /usr/ports -type d -maxdepth 2 -name \*\!:1-1\* -print'
```